# Including template files with phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, cordova

I am trying to include a template file in a phonegap app using ajax with jquery, using the following code:

```
$.get('templates/' + tpl_file, function (template) {
    // Do stuff
});
```

It works fine in a normal browser but doesn't appear to work in the simulator. What am I missing? (and is there a better way of doing includes?)

Comment: That seems to be the accepted way to do it and it does work. What happens when "it doesn't work?" Any errors in the console? The only thing I've had to do was change to the $.ajax function and set the data type as HTML.

Comment: I'll look in to that. It just doesn't appear to return anything (the $.get) on the device itself.